# remove comments in generated mainjs from angular's build

Tags: angular

When running ng `build --prod`

angular creates the minified scripts for production.

The thing is on the generated mainjs file on the last lines it creates something like this:
`module.exports = __webpack_require__(/*! C:\MyProject\src\main.ts */"./src/main.ts");`

My problem is that our security team flags the `C:\MyProject\src` as a vulnerability.

Besides removing this manually, is there any way to configure not to include this on the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in the `angular.json` file the optimization is false on my end.

I was able to minify and remove all the comments on the production build.

```js
"production": {
  "optimization": true
}
```